# Is it possible to put vba code behind BarTender Design and have it run a delete query in access

Tags: ms-access, vbscript, bartender

```
  1.Public sub test()
  2.dim cn, rs, cmd
  3.Set cn = createobject("ADODB.Connection")
  4.Set rs = createobject("ADODB.Recordset")
  5.Set cmd = createobject("ADODB.Command")
  6.connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
DataSource=C:\Users\text\Documents\PrintCenterForm\PrintCernter_v1.accdb;"
  7.cn.Open connectionString
  8.cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
  9.cmd.Execute
  10.End sub
```

Sorry Guys, I posted a picture of my code and error yesterday but for some odd reason they deleted it?

But anyways I am getting an error On Line 8 Stating:"Command text was not set for the command object."

I have also tried rewriting this code as it is doing no good just sitting here waiting for a response but I have also tried this way too but cannot seem to get this to work

```
 1.Set accessApp = GetObject("C:\Users\texthere\Documents\PrintCenterForm\PrintCernter_v1.accdb")
 3.Set accessApp = createObject("Access.Applicaiton")
 4.accessApp.visible = true
 5.accessApp.UserControl = true 
 6.accessApp.OpenCurrentDataBase
("C:\Users\texthere\Documents\PrintCenterForm\PrintCernter_v 
 1.accdb"),false
 7.accessApp.Run "Qry_DeletePrinted"
 8.End Sub
```

I am getting a error on line 1 on the bottom code stating: "ActiveX component can't create object: 'Access.Application' I am more than likely not going to use this code unless you guys see that it would be easier to work with? I also, changed the OnPrintJobStart to OnNewRecord to see if this approach work but first I need to come through the coding issue.

My end result I would just like some code that will kick off a delete query in Access to delete records whenever they are printed from Bartender.

I have a delete query already in Access call "Qry_DeletePrinted".

This database is located on my C:Drive DataSource=C:\Users\text\Documents\PrintCenterForm\PrintCernter_v1.accdb

Just to clarify, I am using MS Access 2013

As you both can see I am nowhere near familiar to VB Script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BELOW IS WHAT THESE GUYS HELPED ME ACCOMPLISH AND IT WORKS LIKE A CHARM!

```
 Dim cn, rs, cmd
   set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
   set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
   set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
   ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data 
   Source=\\NetworkDriveName\PrintCernter_v1.accdb;"
   cn.Open ConnectionString 
   sql = "Qry_DeletePrinted" 
   '+ Format.NamedSubStrings("Printed_User").Value
   cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
   cmd.CommandText = sql
   cmd.execute
   cn.close
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, there is a **VBScript Type of Data Source** in **Bartender Software**.
Create a new VBScript Data Source and set the Script Type as Event Control Scripts.

[image: Bartender VBScript Data Source]

Inside the `Edit with Script Assistant..` choose the `OnPrintStart` and inject your VBScript connection and delete statement code. It will run everytime a label is started to print.

[image: Bartender Script Assistant]

**First, you need to open your Access Database through Bartender in VBScript:**
Source: [Access 2013 Connection String](https://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2013/)

```
Dim cn, rs, cmd
set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

connectionScring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
    Data Source=C:\Users\text\Documents\PrintCenterForm\PrintCernter_v1.accdb;"
cn.Open connectionScring
```

**Second, you can prepare your SQL statement:**

*Note: `Value` in this script means the Value assigned to this VBScript Data Source*

You can choose to get other dataSource value by caling this: `Format.NamedSubStrings("OtherDataSource").Value`

```
sql = "delete from yourTable where key = '" & Value & "'"
cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
cmd.CommandText = sql
cmd.execute
cn.Close
```

Comment: Thanks alot! I am about to attempt this

Comment: attached is my comment below regarding my issue

Comment: @Sebastian no need to have `public Sub test()`, i believe the Event `OnPrintStart` already acted as a method

Comment: @Sebastian you need to have a [proper way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504448/how-do-i-delete-rows-from-an-access-database-using-a-script) to execute your sql command

Comment: Regarding your comment of public sub test(), I had that code under the Procedures for Document Events, then I was calling that sub under the 'OnJobStart'

Comment: @Sebastian did it prompt any error in the Procedures for Document Events?

Comment: Small remark, with the way u set it up I think it will create a problem when printing multiple lines from the database. "OnprintStart" executes one time and it is possible you will only delete the first line and not all the following ones in a printtask. I would advise to run it under "OnNewRecord" so it will execute with each new line. 
Can you provide your error?

Comment: @Wouter good point. At the event of deletion, make sure the data is already populate to bartender ready to print, else he will have no data to populate cause already delete by the event.

Comment: @Wouter  Thank you both for the replies, I have posted a new comment on this thread to hopefully you both can suggest things to my code. Once again Thank you. Please if there is anything that can be easier done feel free to make some suggestions as I am open to ANY at this point!!

Comment: @Raynocerosn see above

Comment: @Sebastian i think you might want to edit your original post instead of keep posting as new answer. and may include `vbscript` as new tag for people who familiar with `vbscript` to help you.

Comment: @Sebastian `Line 8 Stating:"Command text was not set for the command object."` your first attempt already success, just you need to assign the command text. Before `cmd.Execute`  you must assign the command text to `cmd`. `cmd.CommandText = sql` then have your `sql` assign to sql statement

Comment: HUGE THANKS!!!! I appreciate the patience and advice from you both @Raynoceros

Comment: @Wouter See above Thank you Again!!

Comment: While I am happy the problem is resolved it is better to paste this as an answer and leave your original question. Other people with the same problem will have a better view. If my answer was the one that resolved it for you can you please accept it?

Comment: @Sebastian Please choose an answer to mark as correct, else post one complete answer so that people can know what is the solution for similar problem.

Comment: @Raynoceros Let me know if that will do

Comment: @Sebastian You can remain your question, and have a new post of answer that solves your problem, then mark that as correct. So people coming here can learn that you had your solution while looking at your question.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't have a lot of experience with VBscript. I did create something to delete records from a firebird Databse some time ago. It looks to me you don't give a correct command to execute the query / procedure. Below the coding I used with a procedure and which works.

```
Const Connection = "DRIVER=Firebird/InterBase(r) driver;UID=SYSDBA;PWD=masterkey;DBNAME=C:\DB\Database.FDB;" 
SQL = "execute procedure NameOfProcedure " + Format.NamedSubStrings("TELLER").Value
Set dbconn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
dbconn.Open connection
dbconn.Execute(SQL)
dbconn.Close
```

the important part is the "SQL". the procedure has the code to remove the printed line from the database and BarTender just calls the procedure. Of course we need to tell it which line it needs to delete. I use a named datascource for this "Teller". This is linked with the database field ID.